# facebook integration of ios using goviral

Tags: android, ios, facebook, actionscript-3

I am trying to integrate the Facebook on ios , I am coming out of the Facebook when 
I run my installed apk file on Android device . While debugging am getting error 
on the console `isFacebookAuthenticated()` returning false.
The line is:

```
GoViral.goViral.isFacebookAuthenticated();
```